# Selecting single expander within a list

Tags: wpf, listbox, expander

I have many expanders within a listbox and I have requirement where in I need only one to be expanded at any moment in time.

I use the below code from the msdn forums

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter
       Property="IsExpanded"
       Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
  </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
<ListBox.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <ItemsPresenter/>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
          <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<Expander Background="Gray" Width="243" Header="Expander1">
  <StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Eat Me" GroupName="Two"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Eat Pork" GroupName="Two"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Eat at Joe's" GroupName="Two"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Expander>
<Expander Background="Gray" Width="243" Header="Expander2">
  <StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Pork" GroupName="Two"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Beef" GroupName="Two"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Chicken" GroupName="Two"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Expander>
<Expander Background="Gray" Width="243" Header="Expander3">
  <StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Grill" GroupName="Two"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Bake" GroupName="Two"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Fry" GroupName="Two"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

When I paste this code in a sample app, everything works as usual.

But when I paste it into our projectcode, the single expander selection does not work.
I used an attached behavior to figure out whats really happening.

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="utilities:ListBoxItemBehavior.TemplatedListBoxItem" Value="True"/>
    </Style>

private static void Callback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;

        if (listBoxItem != null)
        {
            listBoxItem.Selected += (s, a) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ListBoxItem selected");
            };

            listBoxItem.Unselected += (s, a) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ListBoxItem un-selected");
            };
        }
    }
```

to my surprise, the selected and unselected event never get called when I put it into my project code. Is there any reason why this is happening.

Can someone guide me?

thanks

Comment: I created a solution on github for this problem a while ago: https://github.com/qqbenq/WpfMultiExpanders

Comment: @qqbenq but is there something wrong happening with the code above?

Comment: The XAML you posted works fine for me (apart from a missing ListBox end tag at the end), so I guess there are some styles in your project overriding defaults for some elements (e.g. for Expanders or StackPanel), but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple selection enabled for the ListBoxes by default... But could you please elaborate on " single expander selection does not work" part? How it behaves?

Comment: @qqbenq the selection mode is single only. In a list of 5 expanders, one expander needs to be expanded at one time. If user expands  a different expander,the previous one, should automatically get collapsed. The above code works fine in a sample app. But in project code, it just wont work!

Comment: @qqbenq I searched available styles, but each one of them are defined with a key